# How to check if a file is opened in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, gedit, lsof

The thing is, I want to track if a user tries to open a file on a shared account. I'm looking for any record/technique that helps me know if the concerned file is opened, at run time.

I want to create a script which monitors if the file is open, and if it is, I want it to send an alert to a particular email address. The file I'm thinking of is a regular file.

I tried using `lsof | grep filename` for checking if a file is open in gedit, but the command doesn't return anything.

Actually, I'm trying this for a pet project, and thus the question.

Answer (score 12):

The command `lsof -t filename` shows the IDs of all processes that have the particular file opened. `lsof -t filename | wc -w` gives you the number of processes currently accessing the file.

Comment: I would recommend `wc -l` instead of `wc -w` which works in more cases and `lsof` is not going to put more than one filename per line.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a file has been read into an editor like gedit does not mean that the file is still open. The editor most likely opens the file, reads its contents and then closes the file. After you have edited the file you have the choice to overwrite the existing file or save as another file.

Answer (score 3):

You could (in addition of other answers) use the Linux-specific [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities.

<sup>I am understanding that you want to track one (or a few) particular given file, with a fixed file path (actually a given i-node). E.g. you would want to track when `/var/run/foobar` is accessed or modified, and do something when that happens</sup>

In particular, you might want to install and use [incrond(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) and configure it thru [incrontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)

If you want **to run a script when some given file** (on a native local, e.g. Ext4, BTRS, ... but not NFS file system) **is accessed or modified, use *inotify*** `incrond` is exactly done for that purpose.

<sup>PS. AFAIK, `inotify` don't work well for remote network files, e.g. NFS filesystems (in particular when another NFS client machine is modifying a file).</sup>

If the files you are fond of are somehow source files, you might be interested by revision control systems (like [git](http://git-scm.com/)) or builder systems (like [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)); in a certain way these tools are related to file modification.

You could also have the particular file system sits in some [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem, and write your own [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) daemon.

If you can restrict and modify the programs accessing the file, you might want to use advisory [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29), e.g. [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html), [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html).

Perhaps the data sitting in the file should be in some [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) (e.g. [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or a real DBMS like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) ou [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/)). [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties are important ....

Notice that the [filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) and the [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) options may matter a lot.

You might want to use the [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) command.

<sup>It is difficult to help more without understanding the real use case and the motivation. You should avoid some [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)</sup>

Probably, the workflow is wrong (having a shared file between several users able to write it), and you should approach the overall issue in some other way. For a pet project I would at least recommend using some advisory lock, and access & modify the information *only* thru your own programs (perhaps [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)) using `flock` (this excludes ordinary editors like `gedit` or commands like `cat` ...). However, your implicit use case seems to be well suited for a DBMS approach (a database does not have to contain a lot of data, it might be tiny), or some index locked file like [GDBM library](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) is handling.

Remember that on POSIX systems and Linux, **several processes can access** (and even modify) **the same file simultaneously** (unless you use some locking or synchronization).

Reading the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book (freely available) would give you a broader picture (but it does not mention *inotify* which appeared aften the book was written).

Comment: Your link to the Advanced Linux Programming book is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls -lrt`, it displays the last RW operations in the shell. Then you can conclude whether the file is opened or not. Make sure that you are in the exact directory.

Comment: "ls -lrt" sorts using modification timestamp. If your filesystem supports it (and in Linux it usually does) you could also use "ls -lrt --time=atime" to see when a file was last accessed.